# Using AJAX with Python Flask, getting a 400 error using a jQuery on click event

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, flask

I am trying to use a card as a button. When the card is clicked I want data to be sent back to the server and then a message sent back. Ajax is working properly elsewhere in my Flask app. In the form (see below), when it is submitted I can get data from it and then display a message back. But when I try and do something similar when clicking a card (using jquery on click), I get back a 400 error. I suspect something is wrong with my syntax, it is different than the version where the request is sent after clicking submit in the form. Is there a way to use AJax without a form? This is what I have tried

index.html

```
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="card prompt mb-1" id="prompt1">
   
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <p class="card-text">
prompt 1 text here
                                </p>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <form id="form">
            <li class="bg-white mb-3">
              <div class="form-outline">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="message" rows="4"></textarea>
              </div>

            </li>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded float-end">Send</button>
        </form>
          </ul>
          <div id="output"><p>output here</p></div>
  
        </div>



  
      </div>
  
    </div>
  </section>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#form').on('submit',function(e){
        $.ajax({
          data : {
            message : $('#message').val(),
          },
          type : 'POST',
          url : '/'
        })
        .done(function(data){
          $('#output').text(data.output).show();
        });
        e.preventDefault();
      });
    });

    $( "#prompt1" ).click(function() {
        $.ajax({
          data : {
            prompt: 'prompt 1',
          },
          type : 'POST',
          url : '/'
        })
        .done(function(data){
          $('#output').text(data.output).show();
        });
        e.preventDefault();
});

</script>
```

routes.py

```
from flask import render_template, jsonify, flash, redirect, url_for, request
from app import app
from app.forms import LoginForm


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == "POST":
        message = request.form['message'] #this works
        prompt = request['prompt'] #this does not work
        output = message
        if message:
            return jsonify({'output':'Recieved: ' + output + ', yay?'})
        if prompt:
            return jsonify({'output':'Recieved: ' + prompt + ', yay?'})
        return jsonify({'error' : 'Missing data!'})
    return render_template('index.html')
```

The error I receive when I click on the card with the id prompt1:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Apr/2023 08:14:00] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 400 -
```